# Can someone explain how the shorthand assignment operator actually works?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, shorthand

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    int x=2,a=3,b=2;
    x*=a/b;
    cout<<x<<" ";
    x=2;
    x=x*a/b;
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting output as:
2
3
while in my opinion x*=a/b; and x=x*a/b; mean the same thing.
Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Comment: With integer division: `3/2` is `1`.

Comment: One of the US investment banks likes to ask this at interview. You there now ;-) ?

Comment: Breaking it down to [TAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-address_code) would have helped you understand what is going on (too).

Answer (score 6):

They are not *quite* the same.

`x *= a / b` is *grouped* as `x *= (a / b)` and `a / b` takes place in *integer arithmetic* (it's `1`).

`x = x * a / b` is grouped as `x = ((x * a) / b)`. the integer division has a less drastic and different effect.

Answer (score 5):

With integer division: `3/2` is `1`.

- `x*=a/b;` is evaluated as `x *= (a / b)` so `x *= 3 / 2` -> `x *= 1`.
- `x=x*a/b;` is evaluated as `x = (x * a) / b;` so `(2 * 3) / 3` -> `6 / 2` -> `3`

Answer (score 4):

> I am getting output as: 2 3 while in my opinion x*=a/b; and x=x*a/b;
>   mean the same thing. Can anybody explain this behaviour?

```
x *= a / b;
//   ^^^^^
```

This is integer division, the rest is discarded and therefore `3 / 2` is `1`.
Therefore the expression `x *= a / b` is the same as `x *= 1` which stays `2`.

```
x = x * a / b;
```

On the other hand is evaluated as

```
x = (x * a) / b;
```

The result is then

```
x = (2 * 3) / 2;
```

becomes

```
x = 6 / 2;
```

which is `3`

Answer (score 3):

Per [[expr.ass]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ass#6) `E1 *= E2` is exactly he same as `E1 = E1 * E2`.  That does not mean that `x*=a/b;` is the same as `x=x*a/b;`.  Since `E2` is `a/b`, `x*=a/b;` is actually equivalent to `x=x*(a/b);` which does produce the same results.